# SQL doesn't do what I need

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with second join in this query. Users have the ability to change order of the tasks which will not affect ordering of other users. However when no order is yet set for the user tasks are not displayed for him because second join does not return results despite it being left outer join

```
select  `workflow_tasks`.*, 
        `workflow_task_order`.`order`, 
        `workflow_group_tasks`.`group_id` as `pivot_group_id`, 
        `workflow_group_tasks`.`task_id` as `pivot_task_id`
from `workflow_tasks` 
    inner join `workflow_group_tasks` on `workflow_tasks`.`id` = `workflow_group_tasks`.`task_id` 
    left outer join `workflow_task_order` on `workflow_tasks`.`id` = `workflow_task_order`.`task_id`
where (`workflow_task_order`.`user_id` = 1 
        or `workflow_task_order`.`user_id` is null) 
and `workflow_group_tasks`.`group_id` in (1, 2, 3, 7) 
group by `workflow_tasks`.`id` 
order by `order` asc
```

Comment: Tip of today: table aliases!

Comment: Do not use `order` as column name

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (i.e. not images.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should apply the user filter in different table than `workflow_task_order`, when you want to fetch tasks of particular user. If that's your only user at this point (what I suppose is true), then your query will not return any results. It's because as you said you don't have "order" records for that user yet, and you don't have neither any entries there for user with `null` id obviously.

I suppose you have `user_id` column in `workflow_tasks` too, then the following query should work fine and result what you expect:

```
select  `workflow_tasks`.*, 
        `workflow_task_order`.`order`, 
        `workflow_group_tasks`.`group_id` as `pivot_group_id`, 
        `workflow_group_tasks`.`task_id` as `pivot_task_id`
from `workflow_tasks` 
    inner join `workflow_group_tasks` on `workflow_tasks`.`id` = `workflow_group_tasks`.`task_id` 
    left outer join `workflow_task_order` on `workflow_tasks`.`id` = `workflow_task_order`.`task_id`
where `workflow_tasks`.`user_id` = 1  
and `workflow_group_tasks`.`group_id` in (1, 2, 3, 7) 
group by `workflow_tasks`.`id` 
order by `order` asc
```

However if you have tasks common for different users (e.g. for a team) and you don't have `user_id` in any other table than `workflow_task_order`, then the following query should be more suitable:

```
select  `workflow_tasks`.*, 
        `workflow_task_order`.`order`, 
        `workflow_group_tasks`.`group_id` as `pivot_group_id`, 
        `workflow_group_tasks`.`task_id` as `pivot_task_id`
from `workflow_tasks` 
    inner join `workflow_group_tasks` on `workflow_tasks`.`id` = `workflow_group_tasks`.`task_id` 
    left outer join `workflow_task_order` on (`workflow_tasks`.`id` = `workflow_task_order`.`task_id` and `workflow_task_order`.`user_id` = 1)
where `workflow_group_tasks`.`group_id` in (1, 2, 3, 7) 
group by `workflow_tasks`.`id` 
order by `order` asc
```

Comment: I don´t use aliases because the query is generated by the laravel.
Sorry guys, I´m new here and I´ll be add the data next time.

1. The user creates a task and a record is created for this user.

2. Another user who has a permission to view a task can see a task list, but because it doesn´t have a record in the order table, the task will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `on` clause.  But your query would be so much more readable with table aliases:

```
select  wt.*, wto.`order`, wgt.group_id as pivot_group_id, 
        wgt.task_id as pivot_task_id
from workflow_tasks wt inner join 
     workflow_group_tasks wgt
     on wt.id = wgt.task_id left join
     workflow_task_order wto
     on wt.id = wto.task_id and wto.user_id = 1
where wgt.group_id in (1, 2, 3, 7) 
group by wt.id
order by `order` asc;
```

Assuming rows really match, your version doesn't work when there are task orders for *other* users but not `1`.  Then the `where` filters out all rows.

Let me mention a few other things:

- Table aliases make the query much easier to read.
- The `group by` is quite suspicious, because you have no aggregation functions in the `select`.  I question what you are doing.
- `order` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.